# increase speed for 'for loop'

Tags: performance, r

I have files containing data set which contain 11,000 rows. I have to run a loop through each row, this is taking me 25minutes for each file.
I am using following code:

```
z <- read.zoo("Title.txt", tz = "")
for(i in seq_along(z[,1])) {
  if(is.na(coredata(z[i,1]))) next
  ctr <- i
  while(ctr < length(z[,1])) {
    if(abs(coredata(z[i,1])-coredata(z[ctr+1,1])) > std_d) {
      z[ctr+1,1] <- NA
      ctr <- ctr + 1
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Where `"Title.txt"` is file containing 11,000 rows. It looks like (first five rows):

```
"timestamp" "mesured_distance" "IFC_Code" "from_sensor_to_river_bottom"
 "1" "2012-06-03 12:30:07-05" 3188 1005 3500
 "2" "2012-06-03 12:15:16-05" 3189 1005 3500
 "3" "2012-06-03 12:00:08-05" 3185 1005 3500
 "4" "2012-06-03 11:45:11-05" 3191 1005 3500
 "5" "2012-06-03 11:30:15-05" 3188 1005 3500
```

I wish to receive help on how should I increase the speed for this code?

Here is how the code works:

```
    set.seed(100)
    x=rnorm(15)
    std_d=sd(x)
```

afer running code. It gives this:

```
    m
  [1] -0.50219235          NA -0.07891709          NA  0.11697127  0.31863009            NA
  [8]  0.71453271          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA  0.73984050
 [15]          NA
```

It replaces the next element(e2) with NA if the subtraction(e1-e2)  is > std_d and then checks e1 with e3 if (e1-e3) is > std_d then it replaces e3, if it was < std_d then it 
would check e3-e4 and so on.

Comment: Is `coredata` an array lookup or a function call?

Comment: its a function call, from the package-zoo.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Since you are creating new zoo objects countless times, I wouldn't be surprised if most of the time were spent in `[.zoo` or `coredata`: if it is the case, extracting the array once before the loop may speed things up.

Comment: okay ill try that...what if this is not the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823971/clean-up-the-dataset.  Also looks like a homework problem with 2 different people on same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Revised: ...I wonder if this could replace those two loops? Here are the results with the test vector offered in your comments:

```
set.seed(100);  m=rnorm(15); std_d <- sd(m)
Reduce(function(y,xx){ if( abs(tail(y[!is.na(y)], 1) - xx) > std_d ) {c(y,NA)}else{ 
                                                                        c(y,xx)} }, 
          m )
 [1] -0.50219235          NA -0.07891709          NA  0.11697127  0.31863009          NA  0.71453271
 [9]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA  0.73984050          NA
```

Here's original test case with revised results. It is now comparing the last non-NA value to the current one and making NA if it exceeds the standard value. That other solution looked at the running sd() but your code did not do that so I just used a global sd value:

```
> z <- read.zoo(text=' "timestamp" "mesured_distance" "IFC_Code" "from_sensor_to_river_bottom"
 "1" "2012-06-03 12:30:07-05" 3188 1005 3500
 "2" "2012-06-03 12:15:16-05" 3189 1005 3500
 "3" "2012-06-03 12:00:08-05" 3185 1005 3500
 "4" "2012-06-03 11:45:11-05" 3191 1005 3500
 "5" "2012-06-03 11:30:15-05" 3188 1005 3500', tz = "")
 std_d <- sd(coredata(z[,1]) )
 zx <- as.numeric(coredata(z[,1]))
 coredata(z[,1]) <- Reduce(function(y,xx){ 
                              if( abs(tail(y[!is.na(y)], 1) - xx) > std_d ) {
                                        c(y,NA)} else { 
                                        c(y,xx)} }, 
                                  zx )
 z
                    mesured_distance IFC_Code from_sensor_to_river_bottom
2012-06-03 11:30:15             3188     1005                        3500
2012-06-03 11:45:11               NA     1005                        3500
2012-06-03 12:00:08               NA     1005                        3500
2012-06-03 12:15:16             3189     1005                        3500
2012-06-03 12:30:07             3188     1005                        3500
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't. Your code detects whether there are any na values. But my code converts the z[ctr+1,1] values, which satisfy the condtion, to NA.
I'll be grateful to you if you can provide something as this short for my entire code.

Comment: set.seed(100)
> m=rnorm(15)
> m
 [1] -0.50219235  0.13153117 -0.07891709  0.88678481  0.11697127  0.31863009 -0.58179068
 [8]  0.71453271 -0.82525943 -0.35986213  0.08988614  0.09627446 -0.20163395  0.73984050
[15]  0.12337950


This what my code does:

 m
 [1] -0.50219235          NA -0.07891709          NA  0.11697127  0.31863009          NA
 [8]  0.71453271          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA  0.73984050
[15]          NA

see this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823971/clean-up-the-dataset
Things in code are perfectly explained there.

Comment: @DWin-I have edited the question to explain the code in more detail.

Comment: Sorry but the solution you provided gives me incorrect output.
I tried using array instead of coredata(z[,1]), but it still takes a long time...around 12min.

Comment: Thats great. Its working. Takes very less time. Thanks